# Using lapply to maximize a function along a grid

Tags: r

I rewrote the question to make it reproducible. Suppose I want to maximize the function `exp(alpha+eta+gamma)` for `alpha,eta,gamma` along a grid of my own choice. I have done this using for-loops but I want to make use of apply-functions to speed up the procedure. Here's what I have done (eta and gamma is here being held fixed).

```
eta=0.11
gamma=0.06
alpha=0.5    
alpha_vals=seq(0.1,1,by=0.1)
eta_vals=eta
gamma_vals=gamma


ml_temp=-Inf

lapply(alpha_vals,function(alpha_v){
  lapply(eta_vals,function(eta_v){
    lapply(gamma_vals,function(gamma_v){
      temp=exp(alpha_v+eta_v+gamma_v)
      if (temp >= ml_temp) {
        ml_temp=temp
        mle_matrix=c(alpha_v,eta_v,gamma_v)
      }  
    })  
  })    
})
```

Outputting `mle_matrix` I get `0 0 0`, so something is clearly not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `invisible()` at the end of each function? This means you are returning `NULL` as your output at each step.

Comment: Oh, had some help by someone, and he added those. I thought they had a purpose, but I guess I should remove them.

Comment: I removed the `invisible()` but my output is still wrong. In this case I get `mle_matrix = 0 0 0` which clearly is functioning properly.

Comment: Can you try to make your code [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?  At the moment I can't run your code, since `loglike_in` isn't defined.

Comment: @Andrie: See the edit. I changed the function to be `exp(alpha+eta+gamma)` instead.

Comment: If you change each `lapply` to `sapply` you'll get a matrix as the result. Then you have to remember that your assignment of `temp` will have no effect, since it only gets assigned in the scope of the innermost function.

Comment: That's true, but it's not the matrix i'm interested in. I'm interested in assigning the value of `(alpha,eta,gamma)` to `mle_matrix` that gives the largest value of `exp(alpha+eta+gamma)`. Changing `lapply` to `sapply` still returns `0 0 0` in `mle_matrix`.

Comment: Do I assume correctly that ultimately you want to give vectors for  `eta_vals` and `gamma_vals` as well?

Comment: @cbeleites: Yes, that is what I want to do in the end.

Comment: It looks like you were trying to use a "closure". Note that you're not setting or accessing global variables here, instead you're defining local variables within the context of the inner-most function. For example, `ml_temp` is only a copy of the outer-most `ml_temp`. Also, you might consider to use `mapply` instead of the nested `lapply`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use expand.grid() and apply()

```
toTest <- expand.grid(
    alpha = seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1), 
    eta = seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1), 
    gamma = seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1))
ml <- apply(toTest, 1, function(x){
  exp(sum(x))
})
toTest[which.max(ml), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I assume that your target function is vectorized. `exp` is, if possible you should try to write your real target function vectorized, too.
2. For the moment, I assume that you can hold the whole of the results in memory. If not, you'll have to `lapply` of one or more of your parameters, but there's probably no need to loop over all of them.

Now here's the suggestion:

```
search.pts <- expand.grid (alpha_v = alpha_vals, 
                           gamma_v = gamma_vals, 
                           eta_v   = eta_vals)
target.val <- exp (search.pts$alpha_v + search.pts$gamma_v + search.pts$eta_v)
solution <- which.max (target.val)

search.pts [solution,]
```

or maybe return

```
list (params = search.pts [solution,], value = target.val [solution])
```

Here's a benchmark on vectorized calculation vs. `apply` for each of the three parameter vectors having 100 values:

```
microbenchmark (
    vectorized = exp (search.pts$alpha_v + search.pts$gamma_v + search.pts$eta_v),
    apply      = apply (search.pts, 1, function (x) exp (sum (x))), 
    times = 10)

## Unit: milliseconds
##         expr        min        lq     median          uq       max
## 1      apply 9569.52277 9687.8617 9940.53103 10140.13430 11413.508
## 2 vectorized   44.37456   45.3286   46.75505    67.38978   314.196
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it is not vectorized and i'm unable to make it so. I will use the suggestion above, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @StefanHansen: I added a benchmark of vectorized vs. apply. If you find your grid search unbearably slow, you may need to reconsider a vectorized version of the target function.